# Unable to getting response when pass parameter to my web service it show Error

Tags: java, android

```
public String CountryCoe(String Country)
    {
        HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet htpget=new HttpGet("http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetISD");

        try {
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(htpget);
            String resp = response.getStatusLine().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, resp, 5000).show();


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", 5000).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", 5000).show();
            }
        return Country;

    }
```

I want to get value of its Country ISD code suppose we pass india then it should return +91
Unable to get response it showing Error  i am calling this function countrycode("INDIA") it showing Error please check where am doing mistake

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `GetISD` method of `country.asmx` service by passing country name as parameter as:

```
http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetISD?CountryName=INDIA
```

also make sure you have INTERNET Permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: OK let me check  but i have write method according to that i need to display its COuntry Code

Comment: i have internet but i have Print suppose i input india thn 91 i should Print suppose if i input US it should print 1

Comment: @user3584311: you can check `http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetISD?CountryName=INDIA` service in browser which return xml with country code

Comment: yes its like this <string><NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <code>91</code>
    <name>India</name>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <code>91</code>
    <name>India</name>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet></string>

Comment: @user3584311 : then use any xml parser like SAX or DOM to get data from xml

Comment: @user3584311 : see [Example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-xml-parsing-using-dom-parser) for parsing xml using DOM Parser\